# Storing all the array values into single variable and then using that value as css property through javascript

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

Suppose i have this array,

```
let array = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  const element = `${i}px ${i}px #0e96ff`;
  array.push(element);
}
```

now is it possible to store all the 100 values into single variable and then use that value as a css property like this:

```
let variable = array;

//css property
let style = { filter:`drop-shadow${vairable}`}
```

if no then how can i achieve the same result?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want with `drop-shadow` specifically:

```
let array = [];

for (let i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  const element = `drop-shadow(${i}px ${i}px #0e96ff)`;
  array.push(element);
}

//css property
let style = { filter: array.join(' ')};
```